# How to change the result of Eager Loading Directly in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables like Class and Student.

```
Class.hasMany(Student)
Student.belongsTo(Class)
```

The following is the query:

```
async function test(id) {
    await Student.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: Class,
                required: true,
                where: {
                    id: id
                }
            }
        ]
    })
        .then(value => console.log(value))
}
```

The output is like :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ppp",
        "age": 13,
        "Class": {
            "id": 1,
            "monitor": "aaa"
        }
    }
]
```

I wish it could be like :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ppp",
        "age": 13,
        "class_id": 1,
        "class_monitor": "aaa"
    }
]
```

I know I can do it by changing the code in `.then()`

But could I just do some changes in this part:

```
await Student.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: Class,
                required: true,
                where: {
                    id: id
                }
            }
        ]
    })
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. I think you have to parse the data in the .then()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raw : true` :

```
Student.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Class,
            required: true,
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        }
    ],
    raw : true,
});
```

but this will produce the result with `.` instead of `_` ,

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ppp",
        "age": 13,
        "class.id": 1,
        "class.monitor": "aaa"
    }
]
```

> 1) Another way is to create alias with attribute name ,
>
> OR
>
> 2) receive the data then you can modifyonce you